# Entity Framework does not throw an error, but I see it in debug mode

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have the following code which incorrectly includes `.Equals(userUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`.

My question is why the code doesn't throw an exception. The `CreateOrUpdateUserAsync()` method exits in the line

```
User? user = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

However, the try in the controller does catch an error. Why not?

Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("user")]
public ActionResult UpdateUser([FromBody] Useruser)
{
    if (user == null) return BadRequest("Invalid user");

    try
    {
        this._myUserRepository.CreateOrUpdateUserAsync(userS);

        return StatusCode(((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

Repository:

Error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(u => u.UserId.Equals(value: __user_UserId_0, comparisonType: OrdinalIgnoreCase))' could not be translated.
>
> Additional information: Translation of the 'string.Equals' overload with a 'StringComparison' parameter is not supported. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2129535 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `await` your `async` method invocation:

```cs
public async ActionResult UpdateUser([FromBody] UserSetting userSetting)
{
    // ...
    try
    {
        await this._myUserRepository.CreateOrUpdateUserSettingAsync(userSetting);

        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Otherwise this is basically a fire-and-forget task which can lead to multiple problems (like unobserved exceptions, or "premature" disposal of resources like `DbContext`)

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I missed that. Time to call it a day. Thanks!